# Why does overriding a non virtual function not cause compilation error?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I tried running this code in the compiler and it gave an output of "circle":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class figure{
    public:
    void print(){cout << "figure";};
};

class circle: public figure{
    public:
    void print(){cout << "circle";};
};

int main() {
    circle c;
    c.print();
}
```

I did not set the print function as a virtual yet it still had the same effect. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Call it with `((figure *)&c)->print();` and you will see the difference.

Comment: You doing polymorphism wrong.  Change `main` to `figure* foo = new circle; foo->print();` and see the difference.

Comment: You used the function `Circle::print` and got the output of `Circle::print`. I see nothing wrong here. Did you mean to write `figure &f = c; f.print();`?

Comment: That's not overriding, that's *hiding*. The definition in `circle` *hides* the definition in `figure`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So in other words, I can redefine functions inside the derived class without having them as virtual?

Comment: @NathanOliver How is that any better? You introduced a dynamic memory allocation, pointer semantics and a memory leak when none of those were necessary.

Comment: This is totally NOT overriding. It's just name hiding. You have two functions that have the same name. Both are accessible. If you have an instance of circle, you can call figure::print() or circle::print() explicitly.

Comment: Yes it's totally valid code. ***But*** it's not polymorphic. If you have a pointer or reference to the base class, and call the `print` function you will get the base class `print` function.

Comment: I see, thanks guys/gals.

Answer (score 0):

As you did it, you only call the method *print* from the class *circle*.
Try to do the following

```
int main() {
    figure* c = new circle();
    c->print();
    delete c;
}
```

and you will see *figure*, no more *circle*. As some people said, that's just name hidding. You define a new function in the class *circle* with the same name as the one in *figure*. Thus, when you call *print* on a *circle* object, you call its method.

Nevertheless, if *print* is a virtual method, you override the function. So, when you'll call *print* on a *circle* object, there will be only one function that can be called.

Comment: there isn't any polymorphism happening here because it's not a virtual function. Your code will call print() from the figure class.

Comment: @AlexG Yes, that's exactly the point they make. Did you read the entire answer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to show out.

Comment: @Abrikot your last sentence made it sound all wrong.

Comment: @nwp & AlexG Yes, my bad. It was misleading. I deleted it. Thanks for the comments!